# How to determine that packet receive is a part of first packet using tcp in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

i code socket application using blocing socket and use multithreading..my problem is i want to receive two large packet..as we know tcp must be split large data into multiple packet..this the scenario:

1. i send 6 mb text file and tcp split packet into 2 separate packet
2. at the same time i send 26 mb video file and tcp also split packet into 2 separate packet
3. at my application i recive first part of text file let say it 3 mb of 6 mb
4. and then i receive first part of video let say it 13 mb of 26 mb..

the question is how i know that first packet of text file and first packet of video file is a different data and should handle in different way..(different buffer maybe??)

sorry for my bad english..

thanks in advance..

this some part of my code

ns = client.GetStream();

```
        while (isListen == true && client.Connected)
        {
                while (!ns.DataAvailable)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }


                data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                //client.Client.Receive(data);

                int indx = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, indx);

                if (message == GetEnumDescription(TypeData.Disconnect))
                {
                    isListen = false;
                    server.ClientKeluar = objClient;
                    if (ClientDisconnected != null)
                    {
                        ClientDisconnected(objClient);
                    }
                    thisThread.Abort();
                    Server.kumpulanThread.Remove(thisThread);
                    Server._serverConnections.Remove(this);
                    client.Close();
                }
                else if (message.Contains(GetEnumDescription(TypeData.GetFile)))
                {
                    //jalankan proses pengambilan data
                }
                else if (message.Contains(GetEnumDescription(TypeData.ByteLength)))
                {
                    string length = message.Substring(6, message.Length - 6);
                    int len = int.Parse(length);
                    expectedLength = client.ReceiveBufferSize = len;
                    data = new byte[len];
                }
                else if (message.Contains(GetEnumDescription(TypeData.Image)))
                {
                    typeData = "Image";
                    dat1 = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    index = 0;

                }
                else if (message.Contains(GetEnumDescription(TypeData.Video)))
                {
                    typeData = "Video";
                    dat2 = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    index = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (typeData == "Image")
                    {
                        expectedLength = expectedLength - message.Length;
                        if (expectedLength == 0)
                        {
                            Array.Copy(data, 0, dat1, index, message.Length);
                            if (ImageDelivered != null)
                            {
                                ImageDelivered(dat1);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Array.Copy(data, 0, dat1, index, message.Length);
                            index = message.Length;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (typeData == "Video")
                    {
                        expectedLength = expectedLength - message.Length;
                        if (expectedLength == 0)
                        {
                            Array.Copy(data, 0, dat2, index, message.Length);
                            if (VideoDelivered != null)
                            {
                                VideoDelivered(dat2);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Array.Copy(data, 0, dat2, index, message.Length);
                            index = message.Length;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        expectedLength = expectedLength - message.Length;
                        if (expectedLength == 0)
                        {
                            dataToWrite = dataToWrite + message;
                            string text = dataToWrite;
                            if (MessageDelivered != null)
                            {
                                MessageDelivered(text);
                            }
                            dataToWrite = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataToWrite += message;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

may anyone give sample code so i can get inspiration to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question, but assuming I do, perhaps you can have your application send a handshake packet that lets the server know what to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP protocol take cares of making segments of files and later joining them. You will get complete data in receive.

Comment: There is no example to be giving.  The fundamentals of using a single [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) will not allow you to send two different files simultaneously unless you do that manually. If you do that manually, then there is no way to discern which data is of which file.  If you have a requirement to send two file simultaneously, you need two TcpClient objects.

Comment: do u mean i should make another instance of tcpclient for one client connection?

Comment: Yes on different port. Otherwise you will have to make tcp packet as TcpClient and its underlying API do for us.